# Bind click event to currently active tab

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-tabs

Is there a way to bind a click event to the currently active tab?

At the moment, I'm capturing the active tab through the `activate` event and I can get the active tab's index, but I'm unsure how to add a click event to the active tab.

Preferably the click event would unbind itself when the tab is no longer active.

Would anyone have any suggestions?

```
.tabs({
    activate: function( event, ui ){
        console.log(ui.newTab.index());
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could listen to the `tabsbeforeactivate` event.

In doing so, you can capture the current tab before it is changed.

[**Example Here**](http://jsfiddle.net/6t6yzffa/)

```
$('#tabs').on('tabsbeforeactivate', function (event, ui) {
    console.log(ui.oldTab);
});
```

Comment: I had to change your approach slightly, which meant changing `tabsbeforeactive` to `tabsactivate`. But it worked in the end! Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

Why not just leave the click event bound to all tabs, then upon a click event, check which tab was clicked? You can simply ignore the click if not desired at that moment (i.e. if undesired tab click is detected).

Remember that jQuery-UI tabs are illusionary -- that is, they don't really exist as they appear. The div connected to each tab is just a normal div, and elements inside each tab div can have normal click events. Pretend the tabs don't exist, and treat the tab divs as normal divs.

Here's a jsFiddle demo that shows how the checkbox elements within all DIVs (ie. on all tabs) can be bound to the same click event. Just as an example:

[**jsFiddle Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/bLrmw4zv/1/)

**HTML:**

```
<div id="tabs">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#tabs-1">Tab 1</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#tabs-2">Tab 2</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#tabs-3">Tab 3</a>
        </li>
    </ul>
    <div id="tabs-1">
        <p>Content for Tab 1</p>
        <label for="cb1">Car: </label><input type="checkbox" class="car" id="cb1" />
        <label for="cb1">Bus: </label><input type="checkbox" class="bus" id="cb2" />
    </div>
    <div id="tabs-2">
        <p>Content for Tab 2</p>
        <label for="cb3">Car: </label><input type="checkbox" class="car" id="cb3" />
        <label for="cb4">Bus: </label><input type="checkbox" class="bus" id="cb4" />
    </div>
    <div id="tabs-3">
        <p>Content for Tab 3</p>
        <label for="cb5">Car: </label><input type="checkbox" class="car" id="cb5" />
        <label for="cb6">Bus: </label><input type="checkbox" class="bus" id="cb6" />
    </div>
</div>
<div id="tabid"></div>
```

**jQuery:**

```
$("#tabs").tabs({
    activate: function (event, ui) {
        var active = $('#tabs').tabs('option', 'active');
        $("#tabid").html('the tab id is ' + $("#tabs ul>li a").eq(active).attr("href"));

    }
});
$('input:checkbox').click(function(){
    var cbClass = this.className;
    if ( $(this).is(':checked') ){
        $('.'+cbClass).prop('checked',true);
    }else{
        $('.'+cbClass).prop('checked',false);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
// Getter
var active = $( ".selector" ).tabs( "option", "active" );
```

http://api.jqueryui.com/tabs/#option-active - documentation.

```
if(active===true) {
    // bind click
} else {
    // unbind
}
```